# Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist"

Tags: android-camera2

On **NOKIA 6.1**

## Getting this issue: Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist" on above mobile and i am using camera2 Api with given os : Android 8.1 and CameraHardwareLevel: Level supported: level 3

Please help any one have solution.